# Viewing typescript .ts files in Midnight Commander

Tags: typescript, mc

When I press F3 key in Midnight Commander on a .ts file, I get the message:

> Please install either mplayer or mpv to get information for this file

How to configure Midnight Commander to view a .ts file as text?

Linux Mint 20.1,
Midnight Commander 3:4.8.24-2ubuntu1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most often `.ts` extension is used for MPEG video so MC is preconfigured to play it with a video player.

To configure extension mapping press <kbd>F9</kbd>, choose "Command" menu and in it "Edit extension file" submenu. See [my `mc.ext`](https://phdru.name/Software/dotfiles/mc/mc.ext.html). You need something like

```
shell/.ts
   Open=less %f
   View=%view{ascii} cat %f
```